# how to get the width of a table working in php and css

Tags: php, css

I have the following table and would the following class called .describe_lesson to be wrapped to a certain width but I tried to use white-space:pre-wrap; and adding some width but it doesn't respond well to it. I also did try to use word-break:break-all; but none of them seem to expand the text.. I guess the white-space or word-break is working because it does break but I would like to expand the width of the text...

If I adjusted the line-height to 5em, it does work but I just can't get the width to expand just for that particular row only..

```
<?php
include_once __DIR__. '/header2.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['u_uid'])) {
    header("Location: index.php?practice_diary_view=notlogin");
    exit();
} else {
    include_once __DIR__. '/includes/dbh.php';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM student_details WHERE id = ?;";

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                          if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                              echo "SQL error";
                          } else {
                               mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $_SESSION['u_id']);
                               mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                               $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);



                               $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);


                                   $first_name = $row['first_name'];
                                   $last_name = $row['last_name'];





                                   $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM practice_diary WHERE first_name = ? AND last_name = ?;";

                                   $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                          if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql2)) {
                              echo "SQL error";
                          } else {
                               mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $first_name, $last_name);
                               mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                               $result2 = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
                               $resultCheck2 = mysqli_num_rows($result2);

                               if($resultCheck2 < 1) {
                                   echo '<div class="nopracticediaryview">There are no practice diary records associated with this user</div>';
                                   exit();
                               } else {

                                   echo '<table class="practice_diary_view">
                      <tr>
                      <th colspan="3" class="update_title">Welcome to the Practice Diary Viewing Section</th>
                      </tr>';

                               while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
                                  echo '<tr>
                      <th>Username:</th><td>',htmlspecialchars($row2['user_uid']),'</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                      <th>First Name:</th><td>',htmlspecialchars($row2['first_name']),'</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                      <th>Last Name:</th><td>',htmlspecialchars($row2['last_name']),'</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                      <th>Lesson Title:</th><td>',htmlspecialchars($row2['lesson_title']),'</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                      <th>Describe Lesson:</th><td class="describe_lesson" >',htmlspecialchars($row2['describe_lesson']),'</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                      <th>Hours of Practice:</th><td>',htmlspecialchars($row2['hours_practice']),'</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                      <th>Date of Practice:</th><td>',htmlspecialchars($row2['date_practice']),'</td>
                      </tr>';
                               }

                             echo '</table>';  
}


}
}

}




?>


This is my css:

  background-color: #FAEBD7;
  position: absolute;
  top: 75em;
  left: 4em ;
  border-radius: 1em;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 68em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.practice_diary_view th {
   background-color: #808080;
   padding: 1em;
   width: 33%;
   font-size: 1em;
   text-align: center;
}

.practice_diary_view td {
  background-color: #FAEBD7;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 2em;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1em;

}



.practice_diary_view .describe_lesson {
    white-space:pre-line;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: justify;
    text-justify: inter-word;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    width: 40em;
    height: 2em;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnucK.png)

Comment: I guess the width doesn't do much in this situation?

Comment: An indented code is more pleasant to read

Comment: This is a client-side problem, PHP has very little to do with this. Please provide an example of the rendered HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Your only table cell in the first row has a colspan of 3. All the other rows however have only two cells. Therefor your table doesn't render properly.

If you fix that and the problem is still there, you might have some line-breaks in the text that you get from the database.

---

To make sure, people can help you with your code, you should always reduce it to a [minimal](https://metager.de/r/metager/1a913634a2b4f1636d30850bab223fd887c51f8448b498f8f9820c7114dfe0533672ee61c20c59cd36f36c8b7fcfe58d3dd32b44bbdcf1b7899f16be3c9da8ce/4a593c4bf90c37b5d611099a89c0ac22/aHR0cHM6Ly9zdGFja292ZXJmbG93LmNvbS9oZWxwL21jdmU%3D) example that still produces the problem. In terms of your code: just the html output of your php script with example data and the relevant css. And just a notice that you retrieve the data form a database. With that you could show a code snippet and maybe while doing that you would have already realised, where the problem is.

Comment: thanks for the assistance guys! I will try to fix the colspan first and see if that fixes the problem